# JavaScript proxies : aggregate notifications after array sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, interceptor, es6-proxy

I would like to find a way to get only one notification after an array sort

Is there a way? Thank you

```js
const callback = function () {
  console.log (...arguments)
}
const array = [2,1]
const handler = {
  set (target, prop, value, receiver) {
    callback (prop, value)
    return Reflect.set (target, prop, value, receiver)
  }
}
const proxy = new Proxy (array, handler)
proxy.sort()
// calls two times callback
// prints "0" 1 and "0" 2
// would like one notification : "array sorted"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `.apply()` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) on `Array#sort()` itself:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

Array.prototype.sort = new Proxy(Array.prototype.sort, {
  apply(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
    const sortedThis = Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentList);
    console.log('sorted');
    return sortedThis;
  }
});

console.log([2, 1].sort());
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

...or, if you want the proxy to affect your array only, you can return a custom function if the `property` being accessed is `'sort'`:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const proxy = new Proxy([2, 1], {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    if (property === 'sort') {
      return function(comparer) {
        const originalSort = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
        const sortedThis = originalSort.apply(target, [comparer]);
        
        console.log('sorted');
        
        return sortedThis;
      }
    }
    
    return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
  }
});

console.log('.sort() works:', proxy.sort());
console.log('.slice() is fine too:', proxy.slice(1));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: perfect. The get implementation is more suitable for my use case. Thanks

Comment: Note : ``set` will not be called which is ok !

Answer (score 1):

A viable approach which does not utilize a proxy was to use a generic implementation of an **`around` [*method-modifier*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22method+modification%22)**. The latter can be seen as a specialized case of function-wrapping.

Such a modifier accepts two functions, `proceed` and `handler` as well as a `target`-object as its 3 parameters. It does return a function which again is going to return the result of the `handler` function. The latter does get invoked within the context of the (optionally) provided `target` while also getting passed the `proceed`-function, its own `handler`-reference and the modified function's `arguments`-array.

Thus, based on such a modifier, the OP could achieve the expected behavior by modifying e.g. an array instance's `sort`-method like this ...

```
const arr = [2, 1];

// reassign the array instance's specifically modified `sort`.
arr.sort = around(arr.sort, notifyAboutFinishedTask, arr);
```

... where `notifyAboutFinishedTask` is the `handler` function which implements exactly what the OP is looking for ...

> *"... only one notification after an array sort"*

... Example code ...

```js
// implementation of `sort`-specific `around`-handler.
function notifyAboutFinishedTask(proceed, handler, args) {
  const arr = this;

  // original task.
  proceed.apply(arr, args);

  // additional notification.
  console.log('\narray sorted');
  console.log('arr ...', arr);
  console.log('arguments ...', args);
}
const arr = [2, 1];

console.log('unsorted arr ...', arr);

// reassign the array instance's specifically modified `sort`.
arr.sort = around(arr.sort, notifyAboutFinishedTask, arr);

// invoking sort twice, once with and once without sort function.
arr.sort();
arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>

// implementation of an `around` modifier.
function around(proceed, handler, target) {
  return function (...args) {

    return handler.call(target ?? null, proceed, handler, args);
  };
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I need also to make it work within a Proxy which is also managing accessors. However your answer is very close to, even closer ... I like the link you provided, I try to summarize it here  (code only) : https://gist.github.com/thipages/085aa96a70231b6c54c0660514bfc858. Thnak you.

Comment: @tit ... Speaking of the link and your provided gist, there is actually a repo of mine which does implement ... [_"prototypal and non-prototypal, possibly desirable, JavaScript/ECMAScript function- or method-modifiers which allow the interception, introspection and manipulation of a function's or method's control flow in terms of its arguments, return value and context at such a modified function's/method's call/apply/execution time."_](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/tree/main/src/modifiers)

Comment: Yep, I saw the git library and thanks for all your papers/loc/so. With the gist, I have just tried to have a shorter code that can be understood at a glance and adding a bit of semantics of mine (oops!).